# Java Spring: Upload picture and the picture will not appear?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, file-upload

I am using Java Spring Boot to create a picture-uploading system. The function I used goes like this:

```
public static JSONObject uploadFile(MultipartFile file, String folder) {
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
        try {
            Path resourceDirectory = Paths.get("src","main","resources","templates","img", folder);
            String absolutePath = resourceDirectory.toFile().getAbsolutePath();
            folderCheckAdd(absolutePath);
            File file2 = new File(absolutePath + "/" + file.getOriginalFilename());
            String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file2.getAbsolutePath());
            if (ext.equalsIgnoreCase("png") || ext.equalsIgnoreCase("jpg")) {
                InputStream is;
                FileOutputStream os = null;
                try {
                    is = file.getInputStream();
                    os = new FileOutputStream(file2);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int length;
                    while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        os.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }
                } finally {
                    os.close();
                }
                result.put("Result", "Success");
            } else {
                result.put("Result", "Fail");
                result.put("Message", "Picture not in PNG/JPG format");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            result.put("Result", "Fail");
            result.put("Message", "IO Exception caught");
            
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    public static void folderCheckAdd(String path) throws IOException{
        File file = new File(path);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir();
        }
    }
```

Whereas, the command I'm using to load said picture goes like this.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils;
import org.springframework.util.StreamUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/project/img/")
public class ImageController {
    
    @Autowired
    ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @GetMapping("/{name}" )
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage(@PathVariable String name) throws IOException {

        return setupImage(name);
        
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/{category}/{name}" )
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage(@PathVariable String category, @PathVariable String name) throws IOException {
        return setupImage(category+"/"+name);
    }
    
    private ResponseEntity<byte[]> setupImage (String path) throws IOException {
        File imgFile ;
        Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:templates/img/"+path);
        if (resource.exists()) {
            imgFile = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:templates/img/"+path);
        } else {
            System.out.println(resource.getFilename());
            imgFile = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:templates/img/noimage.png");
        }
        String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
        byte[] bytes = StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(new FileInputStream(imgFile));
        MediaType type;
        if (ext.equals("png")) {
            type = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG;
        } else {
            type = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG;
        }
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .contentType(type)
                .body(bytes);
    }
}
```

When the first code snippet is run, it successfully saved the picture in the resource, therefore, in my PC, the picture appears and are copied. However, when I try to load the picture by using the second snippet, the picture will not load, the "if (resource.exists())" part always returns false. Until I restart my server a few times, then it appears for good. But I believe that is not the ideal outcome.

So what should I do in order to ensure that once I upload, the picture can be displayed without needing to restart my server? Is there another coding that I should have used, or there's another framework as an alternative?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't upload to `src/main/resources` that will break whe packaged as that is the classpath which you cannot upload to. Upload to an external directory instead.